# Why i get wrong output for html markdown?

Tags: php, markdown

I am using the [html-to-markdown library](https://github.com/thephpleague/html-to-markdown), to print the markdown for a h1/h2 tag, but see that it is printing wrong. I believe the sample output should be:

```
Test H1
```

but it gets printed as:

```
Test H1 =======
```

Not sure what is going wrong, but i don't see any errors either. The code prints correctly for h3 to h6 tags, but not for h1 and h2 tags.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use League\HTMLToMarkdown\HtmlConverter;

$converter = new HtmlConverter();

$html = "<h1>Test H1</h1>";
echo $html.'<br><br>';
$markdown = $converter->convert($html);
echo $markdown.'<br>'; exit;
```

Comment: That is proper markdown. See https://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor/#C0ktLlHwMOSyhQAA What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting that for h1 tag, the markdown should contain a # followed by the text, like: # Test H1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using an alternative syntax, see on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Example)

It should be correctly interpreted by a classic markdown parser.

And it's said in Github that this is this underlined style that is used by your library.
See [on github](https://github.com/thephpleague/html-to-markdown#style-notes) on how to change that

Comment: Oh, my bad. I haven't read the Github page completely. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it's works for me

```
$converter = new HtmlConverter;
$converter = new HtmlConverter(array('header_style'=>'atx'));
$html = "<h1>Quick, to the Batpoles!</h1>";
$markdown = $converter->convert($html);
```